# Is there a way to look at the ML used to make a post?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown

I have been to the formatting reference, and the https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

and http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax.

None of which shows me how certain things on done on the site. Is there a way to view the ML used to generate a post? I think that allowing other people to look at a posts' markup would be the fastest way to learn.  Perhaps when I have high enough rep to edit other people's posts or topics I can look then?

For example, [Favorite Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts).

I have no idea how those key shortcuts were made.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98606/favorite-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts/98773#98773 http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/98773/list http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/f82bd425-704f-4ccb-bf03-aa8d77958cb8/view-source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab the post ID of the question in question. It's between the **`question`** and the SEO friendy part of the URL. Just grab the first set of numbers you see really. And then put it in the **XXX** of the sample URL below:

> https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/**XXX**/list

So for this, while you may not have edited it, [you can still see the revisions list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/23801/list) if you follow the above template. Then click the **View source** link of the relevant edit edition.

If you want to play around with how a post will look, [spend some time in the sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox).

Comment: Except that the <kbd> element has been disabled on Meta.

Comment: Well, there is that bit of sadness.

Answer (score 1):

The keys are made with the `<kbd></kbd>` tag. They're <strike><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>!</kbd></strike> no longer fun. [Jeff disabled the `<kbd>` tag on Meta due to abuse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23624/kbd-elements-are-non-existent/23625#23625).